# How to call D-Bus method that expects array of bytes using busctl command line tool

Tags: linux, command-line, dbus, busctl

I'm trying to do `busctl call` of a method that takes array of bytes as arguments (signature `ay`). How do I do this?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
# busctl call ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${THE_OBJECT} ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${METHOD} ay 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0xaf
Too many parameters for signature.
# busctl call ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${THE_OBJECT} ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${METHOD} yyyyy 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0xaf
Call failed: Invalid arguments 'yyyyy' to call xyz.openbmc_project.Control.Haven.SendHostCommand(), expecting 'ay'.
# busctl call ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${THE_OBJECT} ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${METHOD} a5y 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0xaf
Invalid array signature: Invalid argument
# busctl call ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${THE_OBJECT} ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${METHOD} ay '0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0xaf'
Failed to parse '0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0xaf' number of array entries: Invalid argument
```

So, what does it want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to put the length of the array before the values. So in your example that would be:

```
busctl call ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${THE_OBJECT} ${SERVICE_IFACE} ${METHOD} ay 5 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0xaf
```